# Read specific line from different text files in C programming

Tags: c

Alright so i'm still learning C programming and what im trying to do is read a specific line from different text files in the same folder. So what i mean to say is lets say i want to read the names from different text files and display them. Ive been trying to do it but im only able to read text from one file at a time

below is my code

```
void display_medicine()
{
system("cls");

const char *fil  = "Medicines/";
const char *exec = ".txt";
char filename[50];
//snprintf(filename, sizeof filename, "%s%s%s", fil, medicineview, exec);

system("cls");
char medicinename[50];
char medavailability[20];
char companyname[100];
char dom[25];
char doe[50];
char price[20];

FILE *file;
file =fopen(filename,"r");

int num = 1;

if (file) 
{
    fgets(medicinename, sizeof(medicinename), file);

    fgets(medavailability, sizeof(medavailability), file);

    fgets(companyname, sizeof(companyname), file);

    fgets(dom, sizeof(dom), file);

    fgets(doe, sizeof(doe), file);

    fgets(price, sizeof(price),file);

    fclose(file);

    gotoxy(10,3);

    printf("================= %s VIEWING ================" "\n");

    gotoxy(14,5);
    printf("Name:\t\t\t%s", medicinename);

    gotoxy(14,7);
    printf("Availability:\t\t%s", medavailability);

    gotoxy(14,9);
    printf("Company Name:\t\t%s", companyname);

    gotoxy(14,11);
    printf("Date of Manufacture:\t%s", dom);

    gotoxy(14,13);
    printf("Date of Expiry:\t\t%s", doe);

    gotoxy(14,15);
    printf("Price:\t\t\t%s\n",price);

    gotoxy(10,17);
    printf("===============================================");

    gotoxy(10,19);
    printf("Press any key to go back!");

getch();
customerMenu();
}
```

Im able to read stuff only from one text file but not the others

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Then you need to have some sort of loop to iterate through the file names.

Comment: You need some sort of loop if you want to open multiple files.

Comment: You're not even trying to read more than one file here...you just have one variable "file".

Comment: I'm still new to this, which loop should i implement? And how do i display it?

Comment: We're not psychics, we have no idea what you're trying to do. If you want to read from two files, you don't need a loop, just two variables. If you want to read from *N* files, then you need a loop. Learn some basics, write some code, then come back when it doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: i want to read from N files, but i dont know which loop to use, i literally have a submission in a few hours but im stuck on this part. Understand me a bit

Comment: Checkout readdir sysytem call which will read the particular directory and returns the all the files names in that directory. Then you can put a loop to read from particular files. If you know file names already put them in array of string and loop through the array reading one at a time.

Comment: You need to learn about loops first. Find some tutorials on loops, play around. Then, with the new knowledge, decide yourself. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  Please post a [mcve] And a complete description of what you are trying to accomplish.